# Is there a way to have windows ask me which browser I want to use everytime I click a link?

Tags: windows, browser, windows-11, links

I would like to set up Windows 11 so that it always asks which browser to use when it opens links. I use different browsers for different purposes on my computer, and no single browser should be considered my "default".
I use an app called OpenIn with macos and it does a great job but I cannot find a solution with windows 11.

Comment: I saw a post somewhere saying that I can use the openwith.exe app but the windows 11 settings does not allow to set a default app that is outside the microsoft store.

Comment: it’s absolutely possible to set the file association with “open with”. The dialog that is presented doesn’t make it obvious. On Windows 11 22H2 (which hasn’t been released yet) you can set the default browser with a single click with Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an app called "BrowserSelector" on the Microsoft store (https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9P7FSLDKDXH3).
Every time you click a link, it opens a menu in which you can choose your browser.

I've tried it for a couple of days and seems to do the job perfectly

Comment: Does the trick well. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to achieve this can be

In the default browser picker to select "Look for an app in the Microsoft Store"
[image]

Than install any app of the offered (for this example I installed the File Downloader app).

After that choose the app that you installed as your default browser
[image]
[image]

Than uninstall the app that you choose previously

Now every time when you click some link you will get this dialog:
[image]

The only drawback to this solution is that every time you click some link you will need to uncheck the "Always use this app" checkbox or you will need to start the whole procedure again

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have windows ask me which browser I want to use
> everytime I click a link?

Natively, no, not dependent on the link chosen, or which browser to use (that is you cannot select the browser to use when you click a link).

And in the recent past (a decade or so), it has always been this way.

Links open with the Default Browser. You can easily set the Default browser, but that is for all links, and for the browser you select to be Default.

Select the Browser you use most as Default. That is the line of least resistance.

Comment: what about third party software?

Comment: You would have to find 3rd party software. Windows 11 is highly limiting stuff like this.

Comment: It’s as restrictive as Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 is with default browser.  While Microsoft has taken steps to avoid third-party software from setting the default browser, it’s still possible with a single click, but just not with Windows 11 21H2. The way those programs were working definitely had some legitimate security concerns. Yes; The process to change the default browser has also changed somewhat but how the default browser works hasn’t

Comment: It is possible to add context menu items to Explorer: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-apps-to-the-context-menu-in-windows-11/ In the Registry, for HTML and other URL link types, you could try to add "Open with Edge" and "Open with Thunderbird", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I use [BrowserChooser](https://github.com/jopeek/browserchooser). Sadly it seems to be outdated and a bit buggy (sometimes it crashes and is difficult to configure), but it works perfectly for my case. It will give me an option to choose a browser every time I click a link, and also remembering my decisions for certain links to always open in certain browsers. Just what I was looking for.

If anyone will struggle to set it up, I did as so: For executables I copied shortcuts to browsers into BrowserChooser's folder. Keep in mind not to have an extension `lnk` in the file explorer but DO HAVE it in the BrowserChooser's config e.g. `C:\Data\BrowserChooser [Portable]\brave-shortcut.lnk`, that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://github.com/mortenn/BrowserPicker. A default browser replacement for windows to let you pick your preferred browser on the fly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).